# Hide and show div in multiple div aligned side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, alignment

I'm working on an event onclick. I would like to have numerous onclick event in each cells and I want that the div to be equal size (no matter the number) that means the text showing AND that it doesn't the full screen but stay within the width of the border,  and most of all I want to know how can I make just one click event open at a time. Fore example if a user click on the first one I don't want the second to open.

```js
    function show() { 
        if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide() { 
        if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

```css
#opener{    background-color: #07183d; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;}
#benefits{ background-color: #07183d; 
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;}}
a{text-decoration:none;}
a:visited{text-decoration:none;color: white;}
#upbutton {border:1px dotted white;
}
```

```html
 <div id="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show();">SOCIETES: 400</a></div> 
    <div id="benefits" style="display:none;">Part CAC 40 : 15 700<br/>Part Filiales +100M€: 9 700<br/>% contacts IT: 21% 
           <div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide();">fermer</a></div> 
    </div> 

 <div id="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show();">CONTACTS: 400</a></div> 
    <div id="benefits" style="display:none;">Part CAC 40 : 15 700<br/>Part Filiales +100M€: 9 700<br/>% contacts IT: 21% 
           <div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide();">fermer</a></div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: First of all, id is used for individual / unique elements. You cannot make use of the same id for two different divs as it applies to only 1 and overwrites the other. Use different id and it would work fine. And if you want them to have same CSS, use class instead of id, but for accessing the elements using javascript use the different ids instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it displayed like this? Or do you want to hide the other one once one of them is displayed? 
How the following code works:

- We changed the id to classes to apply the same CSS style as demonstrated below.
- Each of the div tags can have a seperate id say b1,b2 and so on. For this, we can call the hide and show functions by passing the parameter '1' for b1, '2' for b2 and so on.
- When we obtain the id in the javascript function, we just append the passed parameter with 'b'. Example : For b1 when onclick is invoked, the javascript gets the id by ('b'+1) which is b1 and applies the css for it individually. The same criteria is applied for both show() and hide() and it works as you can see from the code snippet below.

Hope, it helps.

```js
function show(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

```css
.opener {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.benefits {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width:300px;
}


}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#upbutton {
  border: 1px dotted white;
}
```

```html
<div class="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('1');">SOCIETES: 400</a></div>
<div class="benefits" id="b1" style="display:none;">Part CAC 40 : 15 700<br/>Part Filiales +100M€: 9 700<br/>% contacts IT: 21%
  <div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('1');">fermer</a></div>
</div>

<div class="opener"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('2');">CONTACTS: 400</a></div>
<div class="benefits" id="b2" style="display:none;">Part CAC 80 : 30 923<br/>Part Filiales +300M€: 3 600<br/>% contacts cs: 51%
  <div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('2');">fermer</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want at first both of the div to be hidden . Then wheb we click on one the text attached to it display. For the second div I've not put text yet but each div will have diffrent text and I don't want when I click on one div the two opens (and I will probably add other div so..) Thanks if you can help me

Comment: @Krystel_T Run the code snippet above, and see if thats what you want.

Comment: @Krystel_T I changed the content of the Contacts above, so you can see the difference of the content when clicked to show.

Comment: Yes but is it to have them aligned ? I am not sure but in the CSS I didn't put "width:100%" but the text that shows up take the full screen everytime

Comment: @Krystel_T That is because of the inline-block property you have applied to all of the containers, parent and child. To have that and reduce the size, just set the width of the .benefits class to a fixed value like I just changed in my code above.

Comment: Oh ok got it but I'm sorry I'm learning so if I want to stay in the same line beacuse I thought if I reduce the background-color width it will keep the div on the same line but it did not, when we click on one the others go down

Comment: No it doesn't work like that, you should try to refer some online sources for CSS styling maybe from w3schools, It might help you out on clearing your basics for that.